# Делаю сравнение в самом ng-if - вылетает ошибка

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<span class="diff curls" ng-if="{diffInMiliseconds > 60000}"> ( + </span>
```

Ошибка > unexpected token

Наверное надо экранировать этот символ чтобы условие отработало или в ng-if вообще нельзя условия сравнения ставить?

Comment: в чем смысл фигурных скобок тут?

Comment: Я думала это как выражение. Не нужны? Я просто новичок.

Comment: да, они не нужны.

Comment: без них ошибки нет, но не отрабатывает

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не отрабатывает?

Comment: если верно, то должен показать span со строкой ( +

Comment: там может быть просто условие не выполняется, то есть значение `diffInMiliseconds` меньше 60000

Comment: Если ставлю меньше - тоже не выполняется.

Comment: Без [mcve] можно только гадать. предоставленная разметка корректна, за исключением фигурных скобок. Если при их убирании ты думаешь что не работает, значит проблема в коде вокруг

Comment: Поняла, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение для `ng-if` должно быть корректным выражением ангуляра, в противном случае будет выдаваться ошибка разбора.

В данном случае лишними являются фигурные скобки, если их убрать выражение станет корректным.

Пример:

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="diffInMiliseconds=60001">
  <span class="diff curls" ng-if="diffInMiliseconds > 60000"> ( + </span>
  <span class="diff curls" ng-if="diffInMiliseconds <= 60000"> removed </span>
</div>
```

Comment: нашла ответ - неправильное условие

Comment: @Elina, ну и в любом случае фигурные скобки были лишними. Ты отредактируй _свой_ ответ, добавив описание того что поменяла и как, либо удали его, так как он сейчас слабо относится к заданному вопросу.

Answer (score -1):

```
<span class="diff" ng-if="row.days != 0 || row.hours != 0 || row.minutes != 0">( + 
                                <span class="diff" ng-if="row.days">{{row.days}} д.</span>
                                <span class="diff" ng-if="row.hours">{{row.hours}} ч.</span>
                                <span class="diff" ng-if="row.minutes">{{row.minutes}} м.</span>
                            ) </span>
```

Comment: если у тебя появился новый вопрос - задай его отдельно, если это уточнение для этого вопроса - отредактируй текущий.